# What is the modern version of `procfs1.c` for Linux 2.6.x kernels?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module

I have been following the [Linux 2.6 Kernel Module Programming Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/x710.html), when I ran into the first example from Chapter 5, called `procfs1.c`.

It would not compile out of the box, and after checking various related questions, it still took me quite some time to figure out the correct changes to make it compile and work as intended.

Therefore, I am posting my updated code for people in the future. I am running kernel `2.6.32-279.el6.x86_64`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an updated version of the example that works with kernel version `2.6.32-279.el6.x86_64`.

```
/*
 *  procfs1.c -  create a "file" in /proc
 *
 */

#include <linux/module.h>   /* Specifically, a module */
#include <linux/kernel.h>   /* We're doing kernel work */
#include <linux/proc_fs.h>  /* Necessary because we use the proc fs */

#define procfs_name "helloworld"

/**
 * This structure hold information about the /proc file
 *
 */
struct proc_dir_entry *Our_Proc_File;


static ssize_t procfile_read(struct file *filp,   
               char *buffer,    
               size_t length,   
               loff_t * offset)
{
    int ret;

    printk(KERN_INFO "procfile_read (/proc/%s) called\n", procfs_name);

    if (*offset > 0) {
        /* we have finished to read, return 0 */
        ret  = 0;
    } else {
        /* fill the buffer, return the buffer size */
        ret = sprintf(buffer, "HelloWorld!\n");
        *offset = ret;
    }

    return ret;
}

static struct file_operations fops = {
    .owner = THIS_MODULE,
    .read = procfile_read,
};

int init_module()
{

    Our_Proc_File = proc_create(procfs_name, S_IFREG | S_IRUGO, NULL, &fops);
    if (Our_Proc_File == NULL) {
        remove_proc_entry(procfs_name, NULL);
        printk(KERN_ALERT "Error: Could not initialize /proc/%s\n",
               procfs_name);
        return -ENOMEM;
    }

    Our_Proc_File->uid   = 0;
    Our_Proc_File->gid   = 0;
    Our_Proc_File->size      = 37;

    printk(KERN_INFO "/proc/%s created\n", procfs_name);    
    return 0;   /* everything is ok */
}

void cleanup_module()
{
    remove_proc_entry(procfs_name, NULL);
    printk(KERN_INFO "/proc/%s removed\n", procfs_name);
}
```